# How to style current menu parent and item

Tags: css, wordpress

I really need assistance in a WordPress project I'm working on. One of the pages is having submenus; I want to style it such that if I click on a submenu, both the parent menu and the clicked submenu take on the styling. I have tried targeting and styling `current-menu-parent` and `current-menu-item` classes as seen on inspect element but it doesn't achieve my desired result. Also tried with `current_page_parent`/`item` classes, to no avail. Please note that I'm currently working offline with a wamp.
All assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Make an example with your menu and styles so we can help you out more efficiently :)

Comment: the idea is this..I have a main menu all wrapped in a div of "main-menu", consisting of Home, About us, Our Services and Contact us. The services page has sub menu of Our Work and Request a quote. Now, when you click the parent menus (Home, services etc) the current page menu has a font color as styled. However, when any submenu is clicked, it takes on the styling while the parent menu becomes unstyled. What i want is for both the parent and the submenu clicked to be styled. i appreciate your assistance please.

Comment: Copy your menu html tags and insert them into your question. Also add the bare minimum of styling so we can actually see your menu with classes and styles :)

Comment: Thanks. I am working on wordpress like i said,so the html tag isnt that copy-able...http://codepen.io/banklan2010/pen/wzaoKd

Answer (score 1):

The following offers examples on how this works correctly
https://github.com/Automattic/_s/issues/835

**2013 Theme**

```
.nav-menu .current_page_item > a,
.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a {
color: #bc360a;
font-style: italic;
}
```

**2014**

```
.site-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.site-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a,
.site-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.site-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a {
color: #55d737;
font-weight: 900;
}
```

**2015**

```
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a {
font-weight: 700;
}
```

Use page inspect to see how the menu is labelled

Answer (score 0):

The parent page will not have the class "current_page_item" or "current-menu-item" anymore, because now the child-page is the current.

To easily solve this, Wordpress adds another class to the parent menu-item of the current page. The class is called "current_page_ancestor", so apply the desired styling to this class aswell.

Comment: Thank u @ninja. I tried that but all the submenus became styled. there must be something i'm doing wrong. Do i need to add the main path?something like .menu-main-menu-container li.current-menu-item a current_page_ancestor